# how to pass URL with whitespace in Chrome and IE or include whitespace without encode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, url-rewriting, whitespace

I have a url to pass on my website that have whitespace. what thing i should done that chrome and IE never encode them. suppose

```
Mywebsite.com/search/ASP.NET MVC 2
```

IE and chrome fill whitespace with  `%20` how i can stop them to do this type of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the whitespace with "_" - this is a pretty normal case. But you will probably not be able to keep your spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Whitespaces are not allowed in URLs. That is why they can automatically encoded by some browser if you call that page directly.

What's the problem with that encoding on the receiver side? Just decode the data or (if you are sure there were only whitespaces) just replace all *%20* with a whitespace.

Comment: ASP.net automatically do that i know but it's looking bad. sometime user feel less to change url to search another.